# Convert Column heights into inches (R)

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, data-science

I am a beginner and I have this data frame with height (x ft' y inches") I need to convert this value to a single number for height in inches

| height_w_shoes | height_wo_shoes |
| --- | --- |
| 5'11" | 5'10" |
| 6'1" | 6'0.25 |
| 6.5.25" | 6'4" |

I need to fix the typo in the last row of column "height_w_shoes" (or maybe not, depending on the solution, currently a "." when it should be a "'") and then convert these measurements into inches as such:

| height_w_shoes | height_wo_shoes |
| --- | --- |
| 71 | 70 |
| 73 | 72.25 |
| 77.25 | 76 |

I am super stuck as I am having a hard time converting these string variables into numeric values. Please help, Thank you

Comment: What exactly does, e.g., `5'11"`stand for? And what's the typo in `6.5.25"`?

Comment: 5'11" stands for 5 feet 11 inches tall. The typo in 6.5.25 is after the 6 should be a ' but there is a period. That value should read as 6'5.25". Also, I need a thorough explanation of the code as I am a beginner.

Comment: Then there's a typo here as well. `6'0.25`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `dplyr` and `purrr` solution:

Test data **UPDATED**:

```
df <- data.frame(
  h1 = c("6.5.25", "5'11\"", "6'11\"", "6'0.25"),
  h2 = c("66.4.2", "7'10\"", "16'11\"", "7'2.50"),
  h3 = c("4'4.2", "7'10\"", "16'11\"", "7.7.77")
)
```

Solution **UPDATED**:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
 df %>%
   # Step 1: correct typo:
   mutate(across(c(everything()), 
                ~ sub("(?<=^\\d{1}|^\\d{2})\\.", "'", ., perl = T))) %>%
   # Step 2: remove trailing `"`:
   mutate(across(c(everything()), 
                ~ gsub('"$', "", .))) %>%
   # Step 3: split strings on `'`:
   mutate(across(c(everything()), 
                ~ strsplit(.,"'"))) %>%
   # Step 4: convert to numeric and perform calculation:
   mutate(across(everything(), 
                 ~ map_dbl(., function(x) as.numeric(x)[1] * 12 + as.numeric(x)[2])))
     h1    h2     h3
1 77.25 796.2  52.20
2 71.00  94.0  94.00
3 83.00 203.0 203.00
4 72.25  86.5  91.77
```

Comment: I think that there is an error in the last row mutate row, everything runs except for the last row " mutate(across(everything(), 
                 ~ map_dbl(., function(x) as.numeric(x)[1] * 12 + as.numeric(x)[2])))" --- I receive an Error : Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
 `..1 = across(...)`.
iNAs introduced by coercion

Comment: The only value this seemed to work on was in column 2, row 3. I think because that value does not have a trailing `"` after the value like the other values in the data frame. I need to remove that trailing `"` from each value where it is present within the dataframe and then I think it will work. Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: Just to be sure: did the code work on the test data I used?

Comment: See updated answer. Does this work now? I've realised you may have not `' '` (i.e., 2 single quote marks) but instead `"` (1 double quote mark). If there are still problems then why not post your data in reproducible format??

Answer (score 0):

Some data insertion errors make this a lot harder then it actually is

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x =c("5\'11\"","6'1\"","6.5.25\""),y = c("5\'10\"","6\'0.25","6\'4\"") )

correction <- function(str){
  output <- str_replace(str,"6\\.5\\.25\"","6\'5\\.25")
  # Corrects first typo
  output <- ifelse(str_detect(output,"\"$") == FALSE,str_replace(output,"$","\""),output)
  # Corrects second typo
  output <- 
    as.numeric(str_extract(output,"^.+(?=\')")) *12 +
    as.numeric(str_extract(output,"(?<=\').+(?=\"$)"))
  # Calculate inch
}               
                 
df %>%
  mutate(across(c(x,y),~ correction(.)))
#>       x     y
#> 1 71.00 70.00
#> 2 73.00 72.25
#> 3 77.25 76.00
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>